# How can I ask a turtle to count the number of other turtles which have a turtle-own value bigger than myself?

Tags: netlogo

How can I ask a turtle to count the number of other turtles which have a turtle-own value bigger than myself?

I made a pedestrian evaluation simulation. In this model, there is a `turtle-own value [dis-door1]`, meaning the distance from turtle to door1. I have to count the number of other turtles which have a [dis-door1] smaller than myself, but I failed. Here is the code with which I am trying to do that:

```
ask people[
  set dis-door1 distancexy 15 0
  set dis-door2 distancexy 0 15
  set density1 (count people with [([dis-door1] of other people) < ([dis-door1] of myself)]) / [dis-door1] of myself
  set density2 (count people with [([dis-door2] of other people) < ([dis-door2] of myself)]) / [dis-door2] of myself
  ]
```

I hope somebody can help to do that.

Answer (score 4):

Your code is mostly correct.

Try the below. Essentially, I removed the outside the of myself because the reference of who myself is refers to the caller of the caller---you have direct access to dis-door1 in the scope of `ask people [...here...]`

```
ask people[
  set dis-door1 distancexy 15 0
  set dis-door2 distancexy 0 15
  set density1 (count people with [([dis-door1] of other people) < ([dis-door1] of myself)]) / dis-door1
  set density2 (count people with [([dis-door2] of other people) < ([dis-door2] of myself)]) / dis-door2
  ]
```